# Как удалить повторяющиеся строки MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица `hf0tv_second`, внутри таблицы одна колонка уникальных значений - `second_id` - и три колонки - `second_en_US, second_ru_RU, second_fr_FR`.
Также внутри таблицы есть четыре ключа (связывающие между собой другие таблицы) - `hf0tv_first_first_id, hf0tv_fourth_fourth_id, hf0tv_countries_countries_id, hf0tv_country_country_id`.

Каким способом можно удалить повторяющиеся строки?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

select distinct тут_столбец_который_повторяется, остальный_столбцы... from hf0tv_second

И вообще, приведите пример запроса и ее результат.

Comment: я зная что среди уникалнова значении невазможна найти павтор, поетаму хачу сделат запрос кроме таблици second_id, и патом удалит по виводам строки second_id
но каким спосбам ето сделат?

Comment: @lamlam, пожалуйста, включи в браузере проверку орфографии.

Answer (score 1):

group by повторяющееся_поле

Answer (score 1):

СУБД под рукой нет, проверьте синтаксис у кого есть возможность.

**Пытаемся понять, что вы считаете повторением**

Попытайтесь привести пример.

Мои телепаты нашептали мне, что повторением вы считаете строки с second_id **1** и **3**

```
|1|any1|any2|any3|
|2|any4|any5|any6|
|3|any1|any2|any3|
```

В таком случае найти строки, где содержатся повторения, можно так:

```
select hf0tv_second.* from 
hf0tv_second 
left join
(select second_en_US,second_ru_RU,second_fr_FR,count(*) from hf0tv_second
group by second_en_US,second_ru_RU,second_fr_FR
having count(*)>1) as B 
on hf0tv_second.second_en_US=B.second_en_US and hf0tv_second.second_ru_RU=B.second_ru_RU and hf0tv_second.second_fr_FR=B.second_fr_FR
where B.second_en_US is not null
```

Пойдет?

Comment: Надо удалить повторяющиеся строки:


second_en_US

second_ru_RU

second_fr_FR

hf0tv_first_first_id

hf0tv_fourth_fourth_id

hf0tv_countries_countries_id

hf0tv_country_country_id




Внутри более полумиллиона строк, проаблема ещо не решена, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: |1|any01|any02|any03|any04|any05|any06|any07|
|2|any08|any09|any10|any04|any11|any11|any12|
|3|any01|any02|any03|any04|any05|any06|any07|
|4|any01|any02|any03|any13|any14|any15|any16|
Ответьте на вопрос, что является повторением:
1) являются ли повторением 1 и 3, т.к. у них совпадают все значения в строке, кроме ключа(second_id)?
2) являются ли повторением 1 и 2, т.к. у них совпадают значения hf0tv_first_first_id?
3) является ли совпадение значений в строке с second_id=2 hf0tv_fourth_fourth_id и hf0tv_countries_countries_id повторением?

Еще раз: приведите пример, что вы считаете повторением!

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/qj0xyj0xr/ удаляют все похожие строки, на фото показано, по каким принципам, проблема в том, что есть уникальная строка second_id.

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Теперь можно двигаться дальше.

Уникальный second_id - это не проблема.

Вы отметили 7 и 8 - я не могу понять, по каким принципам они одинаковые.

15 и 16 тоже не выглядят повторами.

Comment: Внутри базы есть таблицы, первая, вторая и т.д. К примеру, в первой таблице написана страна, потом федеральный округ, потом область, города...

hf0tv_second таблица самого низкого уровня. second_id уникальное значение, остальное это тоже иимена, но с переводом ENG, RUS, FR, а последние колонки ключи других таблиц (дерева).

Comment: Как у вас "Ближнее село" и "Бехлевка село" одинаковый в вашем примере?

Comment: Ну, я хотя бы попытался.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать выборку без дублей или удалить дубли из таблицы? Для выборки можно использовать [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) или `DISTINCT`. Первый группирует строки (убирает дубликаты) по одному или нескольким стобцам. `DISTINCT`, на сколько я понимаю, удаляет из выборки только полностью идентичные строки (хотя возможно я что-то не так понял).

Comment: Надо удалить дубликаты из таблицы, но есть одна колонка с уникальными значениями

таблица: hf0tv_second

колонка с уникальными значениями: second_id

колонки информации и ключи: second_en_US, second_ru_RU, second_fr_FR, hf0tv_first_first_id, hf0tv_fourth_fourth_id, hf0tv_countries_countries_id, hf0tv_country_country_id.